# Запятая после однородной пары в якобы ССП

Tags: запятые, однородные-члены, ссп

Почему в этом предложении не ставится ни одной запятой?

"Плоды этого растения полезные и вкусные и обладают прекрасным ароматом".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант один: *Плоды этого растения **полезные и вкусные и обладают** прекрасным ароматом.*

Здесь **три однородных сказуемых**, союзная связь. Союзы не относятся к повторяющимся, поэтому запятых нет.

**Первый союз И** связывает близкие по смыслу и грамматике сказуемые: полезные и вкусные. **Второй союз** присоединяет к этой паре третье сказуемое.

Этот вариант описан у Розенталя: [§ 13. Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101)

Пункт 8. Если два однородных члена предложения, соединенные союзом И, образуют тесно связанную по смыслу пару, соединенную союзом И с третьим однородным членом, запятая не ставится: Вода давно сбыла в Тереке и быстро сбегала и сохла по канавам (Л. Т.)

Comment: @Sharon, нашла предложение в поддержку Вашего ответа.  *Столтенберг в своей риторике применяет весьма своеобразные обороты, делая вид, что они **белые** и **пушистые** и **поддерживают** мир во всем мире* (из статьи).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма. Я так понимаю, что однородность сказуемых не зависит от формы их выражения.  Или у наших классиков есть какие-то ограничения на этот счет?

Comment: @oleedd   Последний вопрос адресован скорее вам. Есть у вас подобная информация, можете сослаться? Итак, у наших классиков есть какие-то ограничения на этот счет? –

Comment: Однородность бывает разная. Отношение к тому же самому элементу и однородность в прямом смысле (особенно актуально, когда общий элемент в ССП). Второе влияет на стилистику. Пользователи говорили про смысловые группы, но не Розенталь. Опять пробел в правилах. Здесь объединяет в группу то, что та же часть речи. Авторы тестов придумали экзотический пример.

Comment: С пробелами  в правилах это не ко мне. А вообще-то я часто встречаю разные способы выражения однородных сказуемых. Пожалуй,  даже в книжечке посмотрю, но это только ради вас))

Comment: ОЧП могут иметь как однотипное, так и разное морфологическое выражение: Он пишет быстро и аккуратно; Проверка прошла быстро и без осложнений. (стр. 107) https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf

Comment: Да, мы это знаем. Это стандартный пример, а вот у авторов тестов экзотический, но звучит хорошо. Стоп, неправильно понимал это правило Розенталя. Третий однородный член — это просто третий элемент ("обладают"), думал, что у пары должен быть общий элемент, как в примерах. То есть в правилах не пробел, только вот "тесно связанная по смыслу пара" — понятие расплывчатое.